# Uncaught Syntaxterror: Unexpected token ILLEGAL at file Error in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova

I'm working on a Phonegap project. When I try it on the browser and Android emulator it works but when I try  on the Android telephone it doesn't work. Here is the my code that doesn't work on the telephone.

```
function sta_graph() {        
     var selectedGraph = document.getElementById ( "sta_statistic" ).value;
     var url = "http://"+serverIP+"/prtCar11/php/Stations.php/" + selectedStation + "/" + selectedGraph;

     if(selectedGraph != "") {
         var graphObject;
         var xAx;
         var yAx;
         var xmlhttp;

         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();          
         xmlhttp.open('GET',url,false);
         xmlhttp.send();

         var json = xmlhttp.responseText;
         obj = JSON.parse(json);
         graphObject = obj.data;

         xAx = obj.xAxis;
         yAx = obj.yAxis;

         drawGraph('#sta_flot', xAx, yAx, graphObject);
    }
}
```

And here is the Error that Eclipse LogCat gives. Thank you for your helps.

```
05-12 22:18:31.049: E/Web Console(18630): Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL at file:///android_asset/www/index.html#statistics:1
05-12 22:18:38.219: I/Web Console(18630): exception firing pause event from native at null:1
```

Here is my statistics page:

```
 <div data-role="page" class="section" id="statistics">
      <div class="header" data-role="header">
         <a href="#stationpage" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" data-theme="c">Back</a>
         <h1>PRT Yönetim Paneli</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="content" data-role="content" id="content5">
         <select class="span12" id="sta_statistic" onchange="sta_graph();" >
            <option value="">Bir grafik seçiniz.</option>
            <option value="numberOfPassenger">Yolcu Sayısı/Zaman</option>
         </select>
         <div id="sta_flot" style="width: 300px; height: 250px;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer" data-role="footer">
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: whats the code on the first line of the statistics body

Comment: Can you check the first line of your 'statistics' content? Is that clean?

Comment: @ClintonWard I added the statistic page to the question

Comment: i think you need to post all the code, nothing seems wrong with what you posted, try with another phone also